# Check Checkboxes dynamically

Tags: php

[image]Hi, ive been dealing with this for some time now and need your help. well I have an array $arrayAmenities which contains a combination of the following data based on what is fetched from the database:

```
Air Conditioned
Bar
Brunch
Party Room
Tea Room
Terrace
Valet
```

I would like the application to dynamically check the following set of checkboxes based on the data contained in the array. 
With my code only one checkbox is checked based on the first data contained in the array.

Can you please tell what Im missing? Thanks for answering.

code:

```
//get amenities one by one in order to set the checkboxes
        $arrayAmenities = explode(',', $rest_amenities );

        $i=0;
        while(count($arrayAmenities) > $i)
        {
            var_dump($arrayAmenities[$i]);
            switch($arrayAmenities[$i])
            {
                case 'Air Conditioned':
                    $checkedAir = 'checked=true';
                    break;

                case 'Bar':
                    $checkedBar = 'checked=true';
                    break;

                case 'Brunch':
                    $checkedBru = 'checked=true';
                    break;

                case 'Party Room';
                    $checkedPar = 'checked=true';
                    break;
            }


            $i+=1;
        }

    }
```

checkboxes

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:10px">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-top:1px solid #CCC;border-right:1px solid #CCC;border-left:1px solid #CCC; padding-left:5px   ">Air Conditioned <input type="checkbox" name="air_cond" <?php print $checkedAir;?> value="Air Conditioned"></td>
                            <td style="padding-left:10px; border-top:1px solid #CCC;border-right:1px solid #CCC;">Bar <input type="checkbox" name="bar" value="Bar" <?php print $checkedBar;?>></td>
                            <td style="padding-left:10px; border-top:1px solid #CCC;border-right:1px solid #CCC; ">Brunch <input type="checkbox" name="brunch" value="Brunch" <?php print $checkedBru;?>></td>                          
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-top:1px solid #CCC;border-right:1px solid #CCC; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; border-left:1px solid #CCC; padding-left:5px">Party Room <input <?php print $checkedPar;?> type="checkbox" name="party_room" value="Party Room" ></td>
                            <td style="padding-left:10px; border-top:1px solid #CCC;border-right:1px solid #CCC; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;">Tea Room <input type="checkbox" name="tea_room" value="Tea Room" ></td>
                            <td style="padding-left:10px; border-top:1px solid #CCC;border-right:1px solid #CCC; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;">Terrace <input type="checkbox" name="terrace" value="Terrace"></td>                         
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" style="border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; border-left:1px solid #CCC; border-right:1px solid #CCC; padding-left:5px">Valet <input type="checkbox" name="valet" value="Valet" ></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: the HTML code for the checked property is "checked" (<input type="checkbox" name="…" value="…" checked>)

Comment: maybe you could try `switch(trim($arrayAmenities[$i]))` in case there is any whitespace left over after you `explode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all, thank to your advices I managed to get it done:
I made the following changes to my code and it work fine:
First I took off the while and switch and did the following:

```
$arrayAmenities = explode(',', $rest_amenities );
        $elt = implode(',', $arrayAmenities);
```

As for the checkboxes, i just set the following as checked=true:

```
<?php strStr($elt, "Air Conditioned")?print"checked=true":print "";?>
```

I repeated the step above for all the checkboxes and it works perfectly. Thank you all for your suggestion which helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 'checked="checked"';
```

instead of:

```
 'checked=true';
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have the same result which is the only one checkbox being checked based on the element contained in the array. I believe the problem is somewhere else. Please any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try a short approach, will save you a lot of com

```
<tr>
    <td your styles>

    Valet 
      <input type="checkbox" name="valet" value="Valet" 
      <? echo ((in_array("Valet", $arrayAmenities)  )?"selected=\"selected\"":"") ?> 
      >

    </td>
</tr>
```

repeat for each Amenity

Comment: `<input type="checkbox"/>` have `checked` attribute; `selected` is for `<option/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
 // use striaght like this, here don't use the explode function


        $i=0;
 while(count($rest_amenities) > $i)
        {
switch($rest_amenities[$i])
            {
                case 'Air Conditioned':
                    $checkedAir = 'checked=checked';
                    break;

                case 'Bar':
                    $checkedBar = 'checked=checked';
                    break;

                case 'Brunch':
                    $checkedBru = 'checked=checked';
                    break;

                case 'Party Room';
                    $checkedPar = 'checked=checked';
                    break;
            }

        $i+=1;
    }
```

Now check this.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have the same result which is the only one checkbox being checked based on the element contained in the array. I believe the problem is somewhere else. Please any idea?

Comment: Hi selom, check now.  Your are using explode (it convert the string to array simply, so you got two in array in that. It is problem you didnt got anything).  Use implode function (it convert array to string so you got correct result)

Comment: @selom, our work and explanation are all to get the clear of user who asked the question. So no problem if you get solution it is ok for us.  The thing, i consider $rest_amenities is array and i provide the solution.  But you may have the value with commas.